# .bst file: Remove comma after year

Tags: bst

I need to modify my .bst file to remove the comma after the year in parenthesis and replace it with a blank (in the bibliography).

Currently, I have:

> Newey, W. K. and West, K. D. (1987), A simple, positive semi-definite, heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation consistent covariance matrix, Econometrica 55, 703–708.

But I need to remove the comma after "(1987)", that is:

> Newey, W. K. and West, K. D. (1987) A simple, positive semi-definite, heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation consistent covariance matrix, Econometrica 55, 703–708.

I cannot find where to do it and what to change in the .bst file. My .bst file is titled bsttest.bst. The entire code can be find below:

```
%%
%% This is file `jfe.bst',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% merlin.mbs  (with options: `,ay,nat,nm-rev,ed-rev,dt-beg,yr-com,yrp-per,note-yr,jttl-rm,vnum-x,volp-com,jnm-x,btit-rm,pre-pub,edpar,blk-tit,in-col,pp,ed,abr,ednx,xand')
%% ----------------------------------------
%% *** Journal of Financial Economics ***
%% 
 %-------------------------------------------------------------------
 % The original source file contains the following version information:
 % \ProvidesFile{merlin.mbs}[1998/08/17 3.87 (PWD)]
 %
 % NOTICE:
 % This file may be used for non-profit purposes.
 % It may not be distributed in exchange for money,
 %   other than distribution costs.
 %
 % The author provides it `as is' and does not guarantee it in any way.
 %
 % Copyright (C) 1994-98 Patrick W. Daly
 %-------------------------------------------------------------------
 %   For use with BibTeX version 0.99a or later
 %-------------------------------------------------------------------
 % This bibliography style file is intended for texts in ENGLISH
 % This is an author-year citation style bibliography. As such, it is
 % non-standard LaTeX, and requires a special package file to function properly.
 % Such a package is    natbib.sty   by Patrick W. Daly
 % The form of the \bibitem entries is
 %   \bibitem[Jones et al.(1990)]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[Jones et al.(1990)Jones, Baker, and Smith]{key}...
 % The essential feature is that the label (the part in brackets) consists
 % of the author names, as they should appear in the citation, with the year
 % in parentheses following. There must be no space before the opening
 % parenthesis!
 % With natbib v5.3, a full list of authors may also follow the year.
 % In natbib.sty, it is possible to define the type of enclosures that is
 % really wanted (brackets or parentheses), but in either case, there must
 % be parentheses in the label.
 % The \cite command functions as follows:
 %   \citet{key} ==>>                Jones et al. (1990)
 %   \citet*{key} ==>>               Jones, Baker, and Smith (1990)
 %   \citep{key} ==>>                (Jones et al., 1990)
 %   \citep*{key} ==>>               (Jones, Baker, and Smith, 1990)
 %   \citep[chap. 2]{key} ==>>       (Jones et al., 1990, chap. 2)
 %   \citep[e.g.][]{key} ==>>        (e.g. Jones et al., 1990)
 %   \citep[e.g.][p. 32]{key} ==>>   (e.g. Jones et al., p. 32)
 %   \citeauthor{key} ==>>           Jones et al.
 %   \citeauthor*{key} ==>>          Jones, Baker, and Smith
 %   \citeyear{key} ==>>             1990
 %---------------------------------------------------------------------

ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    volume
    year
  }
  {}
  { label extra.label sort.label short.list }

INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }

FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
}

STRINGS { s t }

FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { ", " * write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { ", " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}

FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
    'skip$
    { output.state before.all =
        'skip$
        { after.sentence 'output.state := }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {add.blank}
{  " " * before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {date.block}
{
    new.sentence
}

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}

FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\em " swap$ * "\/}" * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {capitalize}
{ "u" change.case$ "t" change.case$ }

FUNCTION {space.word}
{ " " swap$ * " " * }

 % Here are the language-specific definitions for explicit words.
 % Each function has a name bbl.xxx where xxx is the English word.
 % The language selected here is ENGLISH
FUNCTION {bbl.and}
{ "and"}

FUNCTION {bbl.etal}
{ "et~al." }

FUNCTION {bbl.editors}
{ "eds." }

FUNCTION {bbl.editor}
{ "ed." }

FUNCTION {bbl.edby}
{ "edited by" }

FUNCTION {bbl.edition}
{ "ed." }

FUNCTION {bbl.volume}
{ "vol." }

FUNCTION {bbl.of}
{ "of" }

FUNCTION {bbl.number}
{ "no." }

FUNCTION {bbl.nr}
{ "no." }

FUNCTION {bbl.in}
{ "in" }

FUNCTION {bbl.pages}
{ "pp." }

FUNCTION {bbl.page}
{ "p." }

FUNCTION {bbl.chapter}
{ "chap." }

FUNCTION {bbl.techrep}
{ "Tech. Rep." }

FUNCTION {bbl.mthesis}
{ "Master's thesis" }

FUNCTION {bbl.phdthesis}
{ "Ph.D. thesis" }

FUNCTION {bbl.first}
{ "First" }

FUNCTION {bbl.second}
{ "Second" }

FUNCTION {bbl.third}
{ "Third" }

FUNCTION {bbl.fourth}
{ "Fourth" }

FUNCTION {bbl.fifth}
{ "Fifth" }

FUNCTION {bbl.st}
{ "st" }

FUNCTION {bbl.nd}
{ "nd" }

FUNCTION {bbl.rd}
{ "rd" }

FUNCTION {bbl.th}
{ "th" }

MACRO {jan} {"Jan."}

MACRO {feb} {"Feb."}

MACRO {mar} {"Mar."}

MACRO {apr} {"Apr."}

MACRO {may} {"May"}

MACRO {jun} {"Jun."}

MACRO {jul} {"Jul."}

MACRO {aug} {"Aug."}

MACRO {sep} {"Sep."}

MACRO {oct} {"Oct."}

MACRO {nov} {"Nov."}

MACRO {dec} {"Dec."}

FUNCTION {eng.ord}
{ duplicate$ "1" swap$ *
  #-2 #1 substring$ "1" =
     { bbl.th * }
     { duplicate$ #-1 #1 substring$
       duplicate$ "1" =
         { pop$ bbl.st * }
         { duplicate$ "2" =
             { pop$ bbl.nd * }
             { "3" =
                 { bbl.rd * }
                 { bbl.th * }
               if$
             }
           if$
          }
       if$
     }
   if$
}

MACRO {acmcs} {"ACM Computing Surveys"}

MACRO {acta} {"Acta Informatica"}

MACRO {cacm} {"Communications of the ACM"}

MACRO {ibmjrd} {"IBM Journal of Research and Development"}

MACRO {ibmsj} {"IBM Systems Journal"}

MACRO {ieeese} {"IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering"}

MACRO {ieeetc} {"IEEE Transactions on Computers"}

MACRO {ieeetcad}
 {"IEEE Transactions on Computer-Aided Design of Integrated Circuits"}

MACRO {ipl} {"Information Processing Letters"}

MACRO {jacm} {"Journal of the ACM"}

MACRO {jcss} {"Journal of Computer and System Sciences"}

MACRO {scp} {"Science of Computer Programming"}

MACRO {sicomp} {"SIAM Journal on Computing"}

MACRO {tocs} {"ACM Transactions on Computer Systems"}

MACRO {tods} {"ACM Transactions on Database Systems"}

MACRO {tog} {"ACM Transactions on Graphics"}

MACRO {toms} {"ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software"}

MACRO {toois} {"ACM Transactions on Office Information Systems"}

MACRO {toplas} {"ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems"}

MACRO {tcs} {"Theoretical Computer Science"}


INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}{, f.}{, jj}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                {
                  bbl.and
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
FUNCTION {format.names.ed}
{ format.names }
FUNCTION {format.key}
{ empty$
    { key field.or.null }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor empty$
    { "" }
    { editor format.names
      editor num.names$ #1 >
        { " (" * bbl.editors * ")" * }
        { " (" * bbl.editor * ")" * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.in.editors}
{ editor empty$
    { "" }
    { editor format.names.ed
      editor num.names$ #1 >
        { " (" * bbl.editors * ")" * }
        { " (" * bbl.editor * ")" * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.note}
{
 note empty$
    { "" }
    { note #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "{" =
        'skip$
        { output.state mid.sentence =
          { "l" }
          { "u" }
        if$
        change.case$
        }
      if$
      note #2 global.max$ substring$ *
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title "t" change.case$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.full.names}
{'s :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                { bbl.and space.word * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.key.full}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            'key
          if$
        }
        { editor format.full.names }
      if$
    }
    { author format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.key.full}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
         { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
          'key
      if$
    }
    { author format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.key.full}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
         { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
          'key
      if$
    }
    { editor format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {make.full.names}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.full
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.key.full
        'author.key.full
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem[{" write$
  label write$
  ")" make.full.names duplicate$ short.list =
     { pop$ }
     { * }
   if$
  "}]{" * write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{
  't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
        { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
            { "--" *
              t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
            }
            {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
                { "-" *
                  t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
                }
              while$
            }
          if$
        }
        { t #1 #1 substring$ *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {word.in}
{ bbl.in capitalize
  ":" *
  " " * }

FUNCTION {format.date}
  { year empty$
    { "" }
    { year " (" swap$ * extra.label * ")" *}
  if$
  before.all 'output.state :=
  }

FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title
}

FUNCTION {tie.or.space.connect}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
    { "~" }
    { " " }
  if$
  swap$ * *
}

FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
    'pop$
    { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { bbl.volume volume tie.or.space.connect
      series empty$
        'skip$
        { bbl.of space.word * series emphasize * }
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
        { series field.or.null }
        { output.state mid.sentence =
            { bbl.number }
            { bbl.number capitalize }
          if$
          number tie.or.space.connect
          series empty$
            { "there's a number but no series in " cite$ * warning$ }
            { bbl.in space.word * series * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {is.num}
{ chr.to.int$
  duplicate$ "0" chr.to.int$ < not
  swap$ "9" chr.to.int$ > not and
}

FUNCTION {extract.num}
{ duplicate$ 't :=
  "" 's :=
  { t empty$ not }
  { t #1 #1 substring$
    t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
    duplicate$ is.num
      { s swap$ * 's := }
      { pop$ "" 't := }
    if$
  }
  while$
  s empty$
    'skip$
    { pop$ s }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {convert.edition}
{ edition extract.num "l" change.case$ 's :=
  s "first" = s "1" = or
    { bbl.first 't := }
    { s "second" = s "2" = or
        { bbl.second 't := }
        { s "third" = s "3" = or
            { bbl.third 't := }
            { s "fourth" = s "4" = or
                { bbl.fourth 't := }
                { s "fifth" = s "5" = or
                    { bbl.fifth 't := }
                    { s #1 #1 substring$ is.num
                        { s eng.ord 't := }
                        { edition 't := }
                      if$
                    }
                  if$
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
  t
}

FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition empty$
    { "" }
    { output.state mid.sentence =
        { convert.edition "l" change.case$ " " * bbl.edition * }
        { convert.edition "t" change.case$ " " * bbl.edition * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

INTEGERS { multiresult }

FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
  #0 'multiresult :=
    { multiresult not
      t empty$ not
      and
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "-" =
      swap$ duplicate$ "," =
      swap$ "+" =
      or or
        { #1 'multiresult := }
        { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
      if$
    }
  while$
  multiresult
}

FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages multi.page.check
        { bbl.pages pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }
        { bbl.page pages tie.or.space.connect }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.journal.pages}
{ pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.pages }
        {
          ", " *
          pages n.dashify *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  format.journal.pages
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
    'format.pages
    { type empty$
        { bbl.chapter }
        { type "l" change.case$ }
      if$
      chapter tie.or.space.connect
      pages empty$
        'skip$
        { ", " * format.pages * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ booktitle empty$
    { "" }
    { editor empty$
        { word.in booktitle emphasize * }
        { word.in format.in.editors * ", " *
          booktitle emphasize * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type empty$
    'skip$
    { pop$
      type "t" change.case$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ type empty$
    { bbl.techrep }
    'type
  if$
  number empty$
    { "t" change.case$ }
    { number tie.or.space.connect }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{
  word.in
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume empty$
    { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
      word.in
    }
    { bbl.volume capitalize
      volume tie.or.space.connect
      bbl.of space.word *
    }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{
  word.in
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.publisher}
{ publisher empty$
    { "empty publisher in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
  if$
  ""
  address empty$ publisher empty$ and
    'skip$
    {
      publisher empty$
        { address empty$
          'skip$
          { address * }
          if$
        }
        { publisher *
          address empty$
            'skip$
            { ", " * address * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
  output
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.sentence
  crossref missing$
    { journal
      "journal" output.check
    "\emph{" swap$ * "}" *
      add.blank
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
  new.sentence
      format.number.series output
      format.publisher
    }
    {
  new.sentence
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {booklet}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.sentence
  howpublished output
  address output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    {
      format.publisher
      format.bvolume output
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
  new.sentence
      format.number.series output
    }
    {
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
  new.sentence
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.sentence
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.publisher
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.chapter.pages output
      format.edition output
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.sentence
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      publisher empty$
        { organization output
          address output
        }
        { organization output
          format.publisher
        }
      if$
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.pages output
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {conference} { inproceedings }

FUNCTION {manual}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.sentence
  organization output
  address output
  format.edition output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.sentence
  bbl.mthesis format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title output
  new.sentence
  howpublished output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.sentence
  bbl.phdthesis format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {proceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.editors output
  editor format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  format.bvolume output
  format.number.series output
  address output
  organization output
  publisher output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {techreport}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.sentence
  format.tr.number output.nonnull
  institution "institution" output.check
  address output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  format.note "note" output.check
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }

READ

FUNCTION {sortify}
{ purify$
  "l" change.case$
}

INTEGERS { len }

FUNCTION {chop.word}
{ 's :=
  'len :=
  s #1 len substring$ =
    { s len #1 + global.max$ substring$ }
    's
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
{ 's :=
  s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  s num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$
      " " * bbl.etal *
    }
    { #2 <
        'skip$
        { s #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            {
              " " * bbl.etal *
            }
            { bbl.and space.word * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
              * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.key.label}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
        'key
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.key.label}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            'key
          if$
        }
        { editor format.lab.names }
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.key.label}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
        'key
      if$
    }
    { editor format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {calc.short.authors}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.label
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.key.label
        'author.key.label
      if$
    }
  if$
  'short.list :=
}

FUNCTION {calc.label}
{ calc.short.authors
  short.list
  "("
  *
  year duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "????" }
     'skip$
  if$
  *
  'label :=
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  ""
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv{ } }{ll{ }}{  f{ }}{  jj{ }}"
      format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          "   "  *
          namesleft #1 = t "others" = and
            { "zzzzz" * }
            { t sortify * }
          if$
        }
        { t sortify * }
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.title}
{ 't :=
  "A " #2
    "An " #3
      "The " #4 t chop.word
    chop.word
  chop.word
  sortify
  #1 global.max$ substring$
}

FUNCTION {author.sort}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need author or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.sort}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { "to sort, need author, editor, or key in " cite$ * warning$
              ""
            }
            { key sortify }
          if$
        }
        { editor sort.format.names }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.sort}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need editor or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { editor sort.format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {presort}
{ calc.label
  label sortify
  "    "
  *
  type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.sort
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.sort
        'author.sort
      if$
    }
  if$
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.label :=
  sort.label
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}

ITERATE {presort}

SORT

STRINGS { last.label next.extra }

INTEGERS { last.extra.num number.label }

FUNCTION {initialize.extra.label.stuff}
{ #0 int.to.chr$ 'last.label :=
  "" 'next.extra :=
  #0 'last.extra.num :=
  #0 'number.label :=
}

FUNCTION {forward.pass}
{ last.label label =
    { last.extra.num #1 + 'last.extra.num :=
      last.extra.num int.to.chr$ 'extra.label :=
    }
    { "a" chr.to.int$ 'last.extra.num :=
      "" 'extra.label :=
      label 'last.label :=
    }
  if$
  number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
}

FUNCTION {reverse.pass}
{ next.extra "b" =
    { "a" 'extra.label := }
    'skip$
  if$
  extra.label 'next.extra :=
  extra.label
  duplicate$ empty$
    'skip$
    { "{\natexlab{" swap$ * "}}" * }
  if$
  'extra.label :=
  label extra.label * 'label :=
}

EXECUTE {initialize.extra.label.stuff}

ITERATE {forward.pass}

REVERSE {reverse.pass}

FUNCTION {bib.sort.order}
{ sort.label
  "    "
  *
  year field.or.null sortify
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}

ITERATE {bib.sort.order}

SORT

FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{" number.label int.to.str$ * "}" *
  write$ newline$
  "\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi"
  write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {begin.bib}

EXECUTE {init.state.consts}

ITERATE {call.type$}

FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {end.bib}
%% End of customized bst file
%%
%% End of file `jfe.bst'.
```

Could you please help me?

Thank you

Comment: Which .bst file? Is it a standard one?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. How can we help you if you don’t even tell us what .bst file you want to change?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I clarified my request in the post.

Comment: I see no clarification. What's the `.bst` you're using?

Comment: I have added the code of the .bst file. I hope this helps. Many thanks.

Comment: Please also add a small document and a `.bib` entry that uses this `.bst` file and produces the output you show. Is this a `.bst` file you created from scratch, or are you trying to modify an existing file? If you're trying to modify an existing style, please tell us what it is. Because the posted `.bst` file simply doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, since you've cosen to omit the preamble of the bst file, it's next to impossible to tell how the file is organized. Why won't you just tell us the name of the bst file and where it may be found online?

Comment: Okay, I now created a shared dropbox folder with simplified files and the .bst file. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: No, that's not the way things work on the site. Please edit your question with the relevant code included. And four different people have asked you the name of the original `.bst` file, but you haven't yet told us.

Comment: Ok, I have amended the post. I have given the name of the .bst file and posted the entire code of the .bst file. Is there anything else missing?

Comment: The posted .bst file does not work without errors. Do you have a link to the original source of it?

Comment: The posted file (which is the one I copied) works on my computer...

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Comment: The `.bst` file you are working with is simply broken. It produces output if you push through and ignore the errors, but it does not make sense to modify a broken file. See the `.blg` file for proof. So your best solution is probably to use `makebst` to generate a new `.bst` that does work, or use a different base `.bst` file to start from, or use `biblatex` (if the journal will allow it) which is somewhat easier to customize than hacking `.bst` files.